# RegExp lookahead

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть ссылки вида:

```
<a href="a/b">
<a href="https://abc">
<a href="a/b/">
<a href="http://abc">
<a href="/a/b/">
<a href="tel:abc">
<a href="/a/b">
```

Собираю ссылки с помощью регулярных, надо отобрать ссылки только без "http" и "https". Но судя по всем у не донкоца понимаю как работает lookhead и lookbehind.

Пытался сделать таким образом:

```
/\<a.+?(href=.?)(?!https).+?\>/
```

Но это не работает (мыслил как, находит `<a href="` и "заглядывает вперед" если встречает https то должен отбросить).

Как поправить выражение что бы заработало?

---

Из вариантов можно искать именно ссылки с "http" и "https" заменять тег `<a>` на допустим `<z>` и искать уже так:  `/\<a.+?href.+?\>/`. Но хотелось бы с первым вариантом.

---

P.S. Пользовался PHP preg_match_all, но полагаю для регулярки язык не важен (возможно ошибаюсь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужен не lookahead, а lookbehind.

```js
var text = `<a href="a/b">
<a href="https://abc">
<a href="a/b/">
<a href="http://abc/d">
<a href="/a/b/">
<a href="tel:abc">
<a href="/a/b">`

console.log(text.match(/(?<=href="https?:\/\/)[^"]+(?=")/gi))
```